# Best practice to secure multiple apps user access with Curity based on the SCIM database?

Tags: curity

**Given**

- 2 web apps (A & B) using oauth with token handler pattern
- Two html-form authenticators (one for each webapp)
- 1 user (john) with registered account in Curity SCIM db allowed to access webapp A
- 1 user (jane) with registered account in Curity SCIM db allowed to access webapp B

*How can we avoid user jane to access webapp A if she use the html-form authenticator of webapp A ?*

Indeed, if she try to authenticate on both Curity auth-form (the one from webapp A or the other one dedicated to webapp B) with her login and password, from the SCIM db point of vue, the authentication will be successful. This seems to mean that without any other security logic, she will received an access token with scopes from client configured for webapp A as the succeed to authenticate.

**What is the the right implementation with Curity to make the login fail if jane try to log herself on webapp A ?**

- Storing authorized apps in entitlements attribute of jane SCIM record associated with authentication action ?
- Using token procedure based on values contained in entitlements attribute ?
- ...

**What is the best practice to manage authorized apps for a given user (entitlements?) with Curity ?**

I certainly miss something, But I don't find any blueprint in the Curity documentation explaining this use case and the corresponding implementation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication is the process of verifying one's identity. If the html-form authenticators use the same credential data source (password store) and do not differ other than the name, then they are basically the same. No need to have two separate ones for each app. If you do not want a certain user to login via a given authenticator, you can use an authentication action like the [deny action](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/authentication-service-admin-guide/authentication-actions/deny.html#configuration). But I'm afraid that such a solution does not scale either.

The decision whether a user is allowed to access a resource (webapp) or not is called authorization. Authorization is best done in token procedures. If webApp A and B are different clients, then you can make decisions based on the client. Alternatively, webApp A and B can use different scopes and you can filter on that. Or you can also work with the audience request parameter, I believe.

However, it is best practice to implement user-level authorization within webApp A and B. That means, webApp A and B need some logic to validate the JWT and check if it meets the requirements (expiration time, issuer, signature, scopes and claims including the username...). If jane is not allowed to access webApp A, then webApp A should return an error. Having the authorization server not issue any access token is not enough for proper authorization for apps or APIs.

Comment: Hi @judith-kahrer, thank you very much for your answer that allow me to make some picking to modify the bff token handler. 
The question was also about solving the user's trusted apps list tracking with Curity Community, as the single datasource make the use of SCIM kind of mandatory when we need an account manager. That's why I'm asking on the right way to define user's apps whitelist inside entitlements or somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, if there is no dynamic way to determine that list (i.e. based on the user name like a domain or any other user attribute), I believe having it in the user's entitlements works just fine. You can use an authentication action to read the attributes as described here https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-entitlements-in-introspection/
Then, in a token procedure check the entitlements and only issue an access token if the entitlements allow it and return an error otherwise.